# Xamarin cannot install package System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.3.0 MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin.forms

I Have tried install MySql.Data but for each time I have error about the package does not contain any references etc. That same problem I have got when I was trying install updates Xamarin.Android.Support. I changed in project properties Android Version but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 'Target Framework' in 'Build -> General' section to at least Android 7.1

[image]

Comment: In VS 2k17 its like properties of projects?

Comment: @J.J yes, right click on the Android project and select options

Comment: I tried to add that library to my demo project, and everything goes well. Could you please check, if there is any other error message?

Comment: only with MonoAndroid

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0

Comment: Package System.Security.Principal.Windows.4.3.0:Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms [1.1.0, ), Microsoft.Win32.Primitives [4.3.0, ), System.Collections [4.3.0, ), System.Diagnostics.Debug [4.3.0, ), System.Reflection [4.3.0, ), System.Resources.ResourceManager [4.3.0, ), System.Runtime [4.3.0, ), System.Runtime.Extensions [4.3.0, ), System.Runtime.Handles [4.3.0, ), System.Runtime.InteropServices [4.3.0, ), System.Security.Claims [4.3.0, ), System.Security.Principal [4.3.0, ), System.Text.Encoding [4.3.0, ), System.Threading [4.3.0, )' does not exist in folder C:\Users\Anon\Source\Repos\no\packages'